# Не работает команда вывода QR кода в дискорд

Tags: python, discord

Ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\yeeww\Desktop\Python\discord bot\venv\lib\site-packages\qrcode\image\pil.py", line 5, in 
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\yeeww\Desktop\Python\discord bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\yeeww\Desktop\Python\discord bot\main.py", line 33, in make_qr_code
img = qrcode.make(file_name + '.png')
File "C:\Users\yeeww\Desktop\Python\discord bot\venv\lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 13, in make
return qr.make_image()
File "C:\Users\yeeww\Desktop\Python\discord bot\venv\lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 296, in make_image
from qrcode.image.pil import PilImage
import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\yeeww\Desktop\Python\discord bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\yeeww\Desktop\Python\discord bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
File "C:\Users\yeeww\Desktop\Python\discord bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

Код:

```
import asyncio
import discord
import json
import qrcode
import PIL
from discord.ext import commands
import os


 
file = open("config.json", "r")
config = json.load(file)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT WWWWWORK")

@bot.command(name="rmkhv")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}ping")

@bot.command(name="foo")
async def ping(ctx: commands.context):
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.message.content}"))


@bot.command(name='qr')
async def make_qr_code(ctx, *, args):
    file_name = str(args).replace(' ', '_')

    img = qrcode.make(file_name + '.png')

    try:
        img.save(file_name + '.png')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(os.path.abspath(file_name + '.png')))

    os.remove(os.path.abspath(file_name + '.png'))


bot.run(config["token"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip install pillow` - в консоль

Ошибка: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`, означает что вы не установили саму библиотеку `pillow`.
Если вы в коде будете импортировать какую то библиотеку, например: `import discord` не забывайте его установить.